How do I SSH from machine A to machine B using a server in between?
I have 3 machines, (A, B, and server). The server is accessible everywhere, machine A is only accessible in my university's local network, and machine B is always with me and the machine I use to access the two other machines. How can I access machine A using the server in between since I cannot directly access it from A to B, but I can access the server from B.
Below is a sketch:

The thing is I am not sure of any way where I could ssh to machine A from the server, but the opposite is possible (ssh from machine A to the server) so it's not bidirectional.

The thing is I am not sure of any way where I could ssh to machine A from the server, but the opposite is possible (ssh from machine A to the server) so it's not bidirectional.

Do not any additional information via comments. Instead, please edit/update your original question.

You can do this with a reverse SSH tunnel. This should help.

If "Machine A" is on the same sunbnet as "Server" or there is nothing blocking the traffic you can use IPTables to forward the traffic,
#Change 5555 to whatever free port you want  
#Enable IP forwarding:  
sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1

#Make change permanent:  
echo "net.ipv4.ip_forward=1" | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf  
sudo sysctl -p

#Create the forwarding rule:  
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 5555 -j DNAT --to-destination Machine A IP:22

#Create MASQUERADE rule:
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p tcp -d Machine A IP --dport 22 -j MASQUERADE

#Make the rule persistant for reboots:  
sudo apt install iptables-persistent

Then, to access "Machine A", from "Machine B" ssh to port 5555 on "Server"
If there is a firewall or some other device blocking the traffic from "Server" to "Machine A"
#Create a reverse tunnel from "Machine A" to "Server"   
#Replace user with your username and Server with IP  
ssh -R 2222:localhost:22 user@Server

#Connect to "Machine A" from "Machine B" through "Server"  
ssh -J user@Server -p 2222 user@localhost


Since "Server" is accessible from everywhere, why not just ssh -J user@Server user@machine-a? (Not tested though)
